# What does 'had on' mean here?

Tags: meaning

What does **had on** or **head-on in** mean here? Could you give me the link in dictionary for its meaning.

> It is difficult I think to address these issues **had on** an (or **head on in** ) American fiction.

This is a part of audio record from speech of an American writer.
This is the link to audio, the phrase starts on 52 sec:
https://soundcloud.com/pleasure-philosophy/american-writer-2-1mp3/s-AOcLl

Comment: Missing word: ***the effect or impact*** these issues had **on** American fiction. American takes a capital a.

Comment: Is it right to omit these words as the effect or impact in such expressions?

Comment: Please believe me when I tell you something is missing. **had on** means nothing  here without one of those terms or another similar term. I'm interested in why you don't see that.....

Comment: I think you misheard the phrase "head on," which is a figure of speech meaning "directly."

Comment: Please provide a link to the source since its interpretation has been questioned.

Comment: If this is head on, there are two mistakes: it is difficult to address these issues ***head on in*** American fiction. In which case, an is wrong.

Comment: @Lambie - yes, you are correct. Note that "had on an" and "head on in" sound very similar, especially to a non-native speaker. It would indeed be good to get a link to the actual source.

Comment: This is the link to audio, on 52 sec the phrase starts (if it is 'head on in' explain this meaning as well): https://soundcloud.com/pleasure-philosophy/american-writer-2-1mp3/s-AOcLl

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

> Sunlight **has** an effect **on** paint.
>
> The effect sunlight has on paint is to cause the color to fade over time.

In the second, **sunlight has** is a reduced clause modifying **effect**.

In your example, **these issues had** is a reduced clause but the noun it modifies is missing, so your sentence is ungrammatical.

P.S. I'm not sure why there's an **an** in your example, ***an* american fiction**.

P.P.S. It is also grammatical to say:

> The effect on paint sunlight has is ...
>
> On paint, the effect sunlight has is ...

That is, **on paint**  need not be considered part of the reduced clause, as I had earlier, but an adjunct  phrase.

Comment: I am not sure about  ''an' american fiction'. I have writen it from audio as I understood. Is it possible here to attach audio fragment?

Comment: @Vitaly: I have never done it here but others have. I think you just need to create a link to a URL where there's an audio player that plays the recording. Be sure to identify the location (minutes: seconds) where the speech is found.

Comment: I actually think the OP transcribed the sentence incorrectly.  It should be "It is difficult, I think, to address these issues head-on in American fiction."  That explains the "an" - it's actually an "in" (and the "had" is also actually "head").

Comment: @CanadianYankee If true, it would completely change the question and answer (and also reinforce the need to provide a link to sources).

Comment: This is the link to audio, on 52 sec the phrase starts: https://soundcloud.com/pleasure-philosophy/american-writer-2-1mp3/s-AOcLl

Comment: Canadian Yankee is correct. You misheard. The phrase is "to address these issues *head-on*...", that is, to address them in a direct manner.  Two people running down perpendicular streets can turn the corner and crash into each other "head-on", that is, directly facing each other.

Answer (score -3):

*X has/have/had issues* is a common well-known phrase that means there are problems with X.  It can also be used like this:

> We had issues with the employee.

to say "we" experienced problems with "the employee."

In passive voice, it looks like this:

> There were issues had with the employee.

If we want to use passive-voice "issues had" participially, then it looks like this.

> I wanted to go through all the issues had with the employee to date.

Comment: I have difficulty with 'had on' in 'It is difficult to address these issues had on an american fiction'.

Comment: You can *have issues on X* as well.